# mgo/txn assert uniqueness in collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have been trying to insert user info to my mongodb. Since I want both username and email to be unique, I created an email proxy collection for it.

```
userID := bson.NewObjectId()
emailID := bson.NewObjectId()
tc := mgoSession.DB(DBName).C("transaction")
    runner := txn.NewRunner(tc)
    ops := []txn.Op{{
        C:      "email",
            Id:     emailID,
            Assert: txn.DocMissing,
            Insert: Email{ParentID: userID, Email: email},
        }, {
            C:      "user",
            Id:     userID,
            Assert: txn.DocMissing,
            Insert: User{ID: userID, Username: username, Email: email, RegDate: time.Now(), HashedPw: hashedpw},
        }}
        err = runner.Run(ops, "", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
```

I want to assert uniqueness of email for operation1 and uniqueness of username for operation 2 before insertion. I think I am not using the txn.DocMissing right but I can't find too much information about it on the internet.

Comment: Please show you actual data model and describe your use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

```
// DocExists and DocMissing may be used on an operation's
// Assert value to assert that the document with the given
// Id exists or does not exist, respectively.
```

...

```
// Insert holds the document to be inserted at the time the
// transaction is applied. The Id field will be inserted
// into the document automatically as its _id field. The
// transaction will continue even if the document already
// exists. Use Assert with txn.DocMissing if the insertion is
// required.
```

So what it sounds like to me is if txn.DocMissing is used then the item must be inserted for the transaction to complete. If the insert fails then the transaction will rollback. I don't think it has anything to do with uniqueness. For that you may want to use unique indexes

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Also more information on how Assert works
https://blog.labix.org/2012/08/22/multi-doc-transactions-for-mongodb

Comment: I have already created unique index for these fields. however, the transaction doesn't return err if the insertion fails. It will just insert the transaction to transaction collection. The record inserted to user and email will also have a txn-queue and txn-revno.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with mongo and transactions.  You may be overcomplicating it. If you have unique ids in place then doing a simple insert should work. https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Insert

If you need to do two inserts at the same time.. Just wrap both inserts with a method. -> something like -> func(ids ...) insert() error

Comment: Mongo is also not sql. You could redesign your document to contain all the necessary information. There is no point in doing two separate look ups later.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/1JszrIaZ1Nw

Comment: I didn't normalize my mongodb tables as you can see from above. I just follow https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/ to create multiple unique fields so I have to create an extra table just for email uniqueness. Since these two insertions are closely related, I have to use transaction to ensure both of their completion.

Comment: @wachiu Your model is flawed, then. While mgo provides transactions, I would not rely overly on it, as it is a _driver_ feature. If you want atomic operations, put them values which belong together into a single document.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I can see your point that we should avoid mgo/txn. I just found that I misunderstood docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/ . I can actually create two unique indexes for a collection. Thanks for all your time. I will mark this as answer.